Issue in Next.js build manifest.js file
I am getting this error in _buildManifest.js file. I am not sure how to resolve it. I understand the error that it is saying that the file should contain type of Record<string, string[]>, but it contains an object of __rewrites type. If anybody can tell me what can I configure to resolve this issue?
: ./out/_next/static/-odsiyNLTJ-AH9P5Rvh0d/_buildManifest.js:1:1
@ziffichess/web-client:build: Type error: Type '{ __rewrites: { afterFiles: never[]; beforeFiles: never[]; fallback: never[]; }; "/": string[]; "/404": string[]; "/_error": string[]; "/about-us": string[]; "/account-suspended": string[]; "/activate-battle-mode-v2": string[]; "/auth/login": string[]; "/auth/verify-otp": string[]; "/auth/[[...path]]": string[]; "/battle-mode": string[]; "/daily-league": string[]; "/delete-account": string[]; "/fair-play-policy": string[]; "/invite-and-earn": string[]; "/invite-and-earn/my-invites": string[]; "/invite-and-earn/terms-and-conditions": string[]; "/onboarding": string[]; "/privacy-policy": string[]; "/room/[roomID]": string[]; "/rules": string[]; "/terms-and-conditions": string[]; "/test-sentry": string[]; "/tournament": string[]; "/tournament/[tournamentID]": string[]; "/tournament/[tournamentID]/leaderboard": string[]; "/tournament/[tournamentID]/progress": string[]; "/transaction-history": string[]; "/transaction-history/transaction-details": string[]; "/transaction-history/transaction-details/[walletTransactionId]": string[]; "/waiting-room/[roomID]": string[]; "/wallet": string[]; "/wallet/kyc": string[]; "/wallet/recharge": string[]; "/withdraw": string[]; sortedPages: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string[]>'.
@ziffichess/web-client:build:   Property '__rewrites' is incompatible with index signature.
@ziffichess/web-client:build:     Type '{ afterFiles: never[]; beforeFiles: never[]; fallback: never[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.

I have no idea how to configure it.
